# Is it possible for an NSView to request all drag types?

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsview

Apple's Clipboard Viewer app is tremendously helpful when implementing copy and paste.  I'd like to have a similar thing for drag and drop, but I'm not sure how to start.

Normally the first step to implementing a drop target is to have your NSView call `-registerForDraggedTypes`.  Is there any way to declare that you want to receive *all* possible types of drops?  Or is there a lower-level API that one could use to get the pasteboard without needing to specifically register first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure it works really in all cases but I have successfully be using something like:

```
[self registerForDraggedTypes: @[(NSString*)kUTTypeItem]];
```

Also look up th eother type items.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. This works for almost everything, and might be as good as we can do. Dragging a font from Font Book doesn't trigger it, for example, but I can't find any other app that accepts fonts, either, so I suspect that it's a "dyn." UTI that third-party apps wouldn't be able to depend on, either.

Comment: For completeness, it might be a good idea to include all 8 "UTI Abstract Types" and 9 "UTI Concrete Types" ("that most other type identifiers are derived from" -- in fact only 7 of these 17 are root UTIs, and there doesn't seem to be any way to get "all root UTIs"), though in practice I haven't found anything yet (except things that are probably "dyn." types) that's *not* matched by kUTTypeItem.

Comment: What do you mean by “pasteboard identifier”?

Comment: Ah, sorry, ignore that pasteboard identifier rubbish. This has been copied code where I registered an own UTI in addition to kUTTypeItem and didn't care to think why it was there (just made it more generic for this answer).